# Is window.performance of PerformanceTiming interface asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, mozilla

My team would like to study the network latency in the current system. For this we want to log network events and get the data asynchronously such that the usage of interface wont have affect on current network calls.

What I believe is this that this API is already logging events in browser so lets forget about asynchronous, there's is no network call at all.

Using the interface I was able to develop following script hosted in GitHub:

```
/*
 * This function logs properties using Performance Timing interface info for various events which occur during loading and use ofo current page 
 * Events recorded - 
 * 1 -Time taken to download the webpage from server
 * 2- Time taken to render the webpage 
 * 3- DNS lookup timing
 * 4- TCP connection establishment timing
 * 5- Response loading timing 
 * 
 * For more info visit -   
 * https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#processing-model#processing-model
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming
 * https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/
 * 
 * 
 */

window.onload = function()
{
            console.log( "Performance API  -  "  );
            console.log("Time taken to download the webpage from server  : " + (window.performance.timing.responseEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) + " ms" );
            console.log( "Taken to render the webpage  is : " + (window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - window.performance.timing.domLoading) + " ms" );

            var item = window.performance;
            var timing = item.timing;
            var navStart = timing.navigationStart;
            var redStart = timing.redirectStart - navStart;
            var redEnd = timing.redirectEnd - navStart;
            var dnsStart = timing.domainLookupStart - navStart;
            var dnsEnd = timing.domainLookupEnd - navStart;
            var tcpStart = timing.connectStart - navStart;
            var tcpEnd = timing.connectEnd - navStart;
            var reqStart = timing.requestStart - navStart;
            var loadStart = timing.responseStart - navStart;
            var loadEnd = timing.loadEventStart - navStart;
            console.log(
                'DNS lookup = ' + (dnsEnd - dnsStart) + 'ms ' +
                'Established TCP connection = ' + (tcpEnd - tcpStart ) + 'ms  ' +
                'Response loading = ' + (loadStart - reqStart ) + 'ms  '
            );


}
```

https://github.com/jimmy17x/HTMLPerformanceInterface/

Please let me know what is the affect of hooking up this code in system, most importantly if using this API has any dependency on network?

Comment: Are you asking for a "dependency" or for an "effect" on network?

Comment: No, there are no asynchronous methods in that interface, it just gets you timing data. No, it won't have any effect on the network. Yes, every measurement changes the system, and doing the logging is clearly more work than not doing it, but this will not noticeably affect any performance.

Comment: @Bergi , I am asking about effect on Network and pretty much got my answer . Can you please recommend the best way to achieve my goal here  as per your experience ?

Comment: Doesn't your script work for you? I have no experience with achieving your goal :-)

Comment: @Bergi it worked but the management wanted to develop something which is "pinging" the server .They don't believe this that doing that will actually consume network calls instead of using this interface :-)